# Looking at logs from bottom upwards

Tags: text-processing, pager

Is there a linux command or some way to look at logs from bottom up rather than from top towards bottom. I know about `tail -n <number of lines>`, but is there something that I can actually scroll and go from bottom up?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Some systems have `tac`, which is a whimsically-named backward `cat`.  Without that, you can still do something like

```
awk '{print NR ":" $0}' $file | sort -t: -k 1nr,1 | sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*://'
```

Comment: +1 for tac, did not know about that one :)

Comment: `cat -n` is like `awk '{print NR,$0}'`, so slightly more lightweight.

Comment: I was assuming that systems without `tac` might also lack the BSD-derived version of `cat` (USG-flavored `cat` didn't have `-v`, `-n`, etc.  I think something triggered my "old ****".)

Answer (score 68):

I think `less +G` is what you're looking for — it'll load up the file at the end, and you can use the up arrow (or <kbd>k</kbd>) to scroll back. Within the viewer, <kbd>g</kbd> will take you to the top of the file and  <kbd>G</kbd> will take you back to the end. And <kbd>F</kbd> will scroll to the end and try to keep reading, like `tail -f`.

Comment: n1 +1 :)
If you'll be so kind:
Can you explain how to search the file from bottom up when using less with +G flag?

Comment: @OlegTikhonov Sure. `?` is used to search backwards in the file.

Answer (score 7):

The [`tac`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) command is like a reverse "cat", if that's what you're after.

If you just want to view a file by starting at the bottom, why don't you use an editor or "less"?

Comment: Two problems I see with using editors are paginators: a) not all editors behave properly to network disconnects, meaning that the editor stays around even when the shell sends SIGHUP; b) many editors touch the directory (by creating a swap/temp file), which is disadvantageous if you want to keep the mtime of the directory stable.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `less` and then use M-> (that's the meta key, usually alt, and the '>' at the same time) to go to the bottom of the file.
`less` supports scrolling.

Comment: The “go to last line” function is also usually bound to `>` (without Meta or ESC) and `G`.

Comment: @Chris, I didn't realize Meta wasn't required in less. But that is was you would use in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a nagios check the perl module [File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-ReadBackwards/ReadBackwards.pm) is useful

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to read a file from bottom upward

---

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n elpmas.file # resulting file

ctr_line=0

while read line; do

   let ctr_line++

   tail -n $ctr_line | head -n 1 >> elpmas.file

done <sample.file
```

---

if `sample.file` contains

```
 1
 2
 3
```

the result `elpmas.file` will be

```
 3
 2
 1
```

Answer (score -1):

### Soluction: Combine `tac` with `less`

```
tac $@ | less
```

### Install

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "tac \$@ | less" > /usr/local/bin/tacless'
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tacless
```

### Usage

```
tacless /var/log/auth.log
```

Answer (score -2):

Piping into tac also works, eg:

```
tail -n 3 /var/log/dmesg | tac
```